# angularjs filter/directive that show date time how many before current date time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

i am new in angularjs i have feeling one problem.i have Date time in my angular application that show created date for post.But problem is that i want to convert date time how many time before post is create like

1. 05/20/2018  1:05:02  -> 2s
2. 05/20/2018  11:05:02  -> 1h
3. 05/19/2018  1:05:02  -> 1d
4. 04/19/2018  1:05:02  -> 1m

i am searching angularjs filter or directive for resolve that particular problem
i am faile to finding ...please help ,,

Comment: Quite simple with https://github.com/yaru22/angular-timeago

Comment: Thanks ...but its to long